# Error while connecting to oracle 12c db using vb script

Tags: javascript, oracle, vbscript, qtp, oracle12c

I am trying to connect to 64 bit Oracle 12c database from VB script and code used is shown below.'Oracle in OraClient12Home1' is  the 64 bit driver installed in my system and i am running script in 64 bit command prompt.

Script throws error message '[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified Microsoft oledb provider for ODBC drivers'

Can some one help me to troubleshoot the issue?

Code -

```
strConnectionString="Driver={Oracle in OraClient12Home1}; " & _
        "CONNECTSTRING=(DESCRIPTION=" & _
        "(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)" & _
        "(HOST="& strDBhost &")(PORT="& strDBPort &"))" & _
        "(CONNECT_DATA=(SID="& strDBService &"))); uid="&strUserID &";pwd="& strPassword &";"

Set ADODBConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

ADODBConnection.ConnectionString = strConnectionString 
ADODBConnection.Open strConnection
```

Answer (score 0):

Install Oracle client before executing the scripts.

If installed please set the environment variables for the driver installed.

Link provides the compatible drivers of Oracle client for different types of OS: http://www.oracle.com/us/products/tools/index-090165.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14189460)

Comment: Link provides the compatible drivers of Oracle client for different types of OS